# Saving Text After Text-Swap

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm creating a shipping status report and what I am trying to accomplish, I can't seem to figure out. In my report table I have a button and it shows "Mark as Shipped". If I click on that button it changes to say "Shipped". This is going to serve as just as an easy reporting method for me.

I am doing the text swap like this...

```
<script>
//Getting Shipping Status button to chance from 'mark as shipped' to 'shipped'
$("button").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var el = $(this);
    el.text() == el.data("text-swap") 
    ? el.text(el.data("text-original")) 
    : el.text(el.data("text-swap"));
});
</script>
```

I had to add

```
e.preventDefault()
```

into the code because the page would reload after I clicked on the button.

One of the issues I am having with this is it isn't allowing me to go back to the original. I tried moving e.preventDefault() to the bottom of that code, but it didn't help.

Now the main part of my question is I want this to be able to save after I have selected it. I'm not sure if I will have to scratch what I'm doing, house this in a db, or if I can do it with my existing code... I definitely need it to save once selected though.

Then one last thing. I'm not sure how to do this with just pressing a button. I know how to do it with php, but I am very new to JS.

When I select "Mark as Shipped" I want a time stamp for d - t -y and time to be added in my td row. Is this possible to do with JS?

I'm looking for ways I can accomplish doing all of this. I have looked all over and can't seem to find anything that is similar to what I want.

Any ideas?

UPDATE

I added it all in to the same script as instructed. Now my button doesn't even change at all and nothing is sending to the db.

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: "shippingStatusSend.php",
    data: {action: "Shipped", order: order_id},
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "text"
}).done(function(r){
    //Do your code for changing the button here.
    //Getting Shipping Status button to chance from 'mark as shipped' to 'shipped'
$("button").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var el = $(this);
    el.text() == el.data("text-swap") 
    ? el.text(el.data("text-original")) 
    : el.text(el.data("text-swap"));
});
});

</script>
```

PHP page called shippingStatusSend.php

I just started learning how to do prepared statements so this may be an issue too.

```
<?php
//connection to db
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bfb"); 

//Check for errors  
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf ("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
    $order_id = trim($_POST['order_id'] );
    $status = trim($_POST['action'] );

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO shippingStatus (order_id, status, date_Shipped) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())")) {

/* bind parameters for markers */
            $stmt->bind_param('is', $order_id, $status);

            /* execute query */
            $stmt->execute();


        /* close statement */
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
            }
 ?>
```

Comment: If I'm understanding your correctly, you want the text changed by the button click to persist when the page is reloaded?

Comment: Yes, if I click on the button to change it to say 'Shipped' I want that to remain upon reload or a year from now.

Comment: Is the 'Shipped' Status generated by PHP? or is it just static HTML? To do what you want you need some server side going on.

Comment: No, as of now, it is generated by a click of that button. This is more of a way for an employee to select that it was shipped. I'm very new to JS, but I have a much better understanding for php. How can I get the value of shipped to be changed into mysql with php and JS working together? OR woukd AJAX be better suited for this?

Comment: To change database data on button click, you should use ajax in this case.

Comment: Anyone have any good tutorials for Ajax that is suited for what I'm trying to create?

Comment: Just added an answer with a basic AJAX call in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make JavaScript changes static, you'll need to use some server side, such as using PHP to store the change in a database.

For that, you'll need to use AJAX, which is easy with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "example.php",
    data: {action: "Shipped", order: orderID},
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "text"
}).done(function(r){
    //Do your code for changing the button here.
});
```

Change `example.php` to your PHP script that will make the change server side, and make sure you pass the `orderID` of the order you're changing. In the PHP file, you can access `$_POST['action']` and `$_POST['order']` to get the information from the JavaScript.

Then in the `done` part (which is called after the AJAX has finished), you can update the button. You can also do some error checking in there to be on the safe side. the `r` variable can be used for any response data from the PHP file (for example, if you echo "Done" in your PHP, `r` will equal "Done").

**Edit**

As per your updated question/code, your problem is that you are creating an AJAX call when the page loads, and not on button click. Change it to:

```
$("button").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var el = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: "shippingStatusSend.php",
        data: {action: "Shipped", order: order_id},
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text"
    }).fail(function(e,t,m){
        console.log(e,t,m); 
    }).done(function(r){
        //Do your code for changing the button here.
        //Getting Shipping Status button to chance from 'mark as shipped' to 'shipped'
        el.text() == el.data("text-swap") 
        ? el.text(el.data("text-original")) 
        : el.text(el.data("text-swap"));
    });
});
```

**Update**
To get `order_id` you'll need to store it in the DOM somewhere. As per your comments you have it in:

```
<td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['order_id']; ?> </td>
```

So something like:

```
var order_id = $('.tdproduct').text();
```

will get the id, but only if you only have one element with that class. Otherwise you'll have to store in some other unique element to grab.

**Saving On Reload**

Once you have the value saved in the database, you need to have PHP render it on page load. Rather than having your static html saying `Mark as Shipped`, use a PHP `echo` or `print` to output the information from the database.

Comment: Thanks for providing me with this. I tried to integrate this and create my php file to send to my db. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but now the button doesn't changed to 'Shipped' nor does the file send. I updated my question with the code I just created. Do you see anything wrong?

Comment: @Paul That sounds like the AJAX call isn't being successful. I updated my answer to include a fail callback. It will log to the javascript console the error object (e), the type (t) and the message (m). You'll need to use that for debugging.

Comment: The only error I'm getting is an unexpected token on line 410.. I don't even have that many lines in my file. I'm looking in the console for errors. Is there anywhere else I can look?

Comment: @Paul can you show me the full error? The console should show you the file the error is in, and if you click on it will take your right to the line.

Comment: At first it was an unexpected token for the ending ). I removed that and then there was an unexpected token for the ending }. So I removed that and the semi-colon. So in your latest answer the last line I removed that. Now I'm getting this error in the consolle... Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on(...).done is not a function....This is for this line ..... }).done(function(r){

Comment: @Paul, take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t8rn0b04/), the only error I'm getting is the 404 not found for the ajax call. Sounds like something else in your code is wrong.

Comment: I played around with this more and I see something I was doing wrong, but I'm getting a new error now. Uncaught ReferenceError: order_id is not defined...How can I define order_id? I'm getting the order_id with a while loop via php... like  this <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['order_id']; ?> </td>

Comment: @Paul you'll need something like `var order_id = $(".tdproduct").text();`, Assuming you only have one `.tdproduct`, otherwise you might need some other identifier. I'll add some examples in my answer.

Comment: I was able to get the order_id to go through and for this to send to my db, but after I leave the page the item I selected goes back to "Mark as Shipped". My changes are not being saved.

Comment: So, would I put the echo in...   data: {action: "Shipped",...instead of it saying "Shipped"?

Comment: @Paul, the best solution is that you have two states using an `if/else` in PHP. If shipped, show the shipped text, and any other changes you would normally make with JS. Else, show mark as shipped, and show everything you would normally have to press.